# How to correct Firebase Cloud Function admin reference not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've recently tried to update .WriteOn cloud function into a scheduled cloud function for my firebase app.  The objective is to run a function every 4 days that goes out deletes messages that are over 2 days old.  This worked perfectly for the .WriteOn function but of course that meant the function was executed every time a message was created; which was overkill.  Here is the function I have in my index.js file...

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

    exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 96 hours').onRun(async (context) => {
      const ref = admin.database().reference('messages/{pushId}');
      var now = Date.now();
      var cutoff = now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timeStamp').endAt(cutoff);
      return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        var updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          updates[child.key] = null
        });
        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        return ref.update(updates);
      });
    });
```

Here is the execution error I'm reading on my Firebase Functions console...

> scheduledFunction TypeError: admin.database(...).reference is not a
> function

Comment: Instead of WriteOn, I think you meant to say onWrite.

Comment: Also I removed the tag and all references to Flutter, but it's not at all involved here.  This is entirely JavaScript on Cloud Functions running nodejs.  Nothing about this changes based on the client app's language or platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that this line of code is calling a method that doesn't exist:

```
  const ref = admin.database().reference('messages/{pushId}');
```

In fact, there is no method called "reference" on the Database object returned by `admin.database()`.  Using the API documentation, you can see that [database()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.md#database) returns a [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.database.database.md#database_interface) object which further extends a different [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Database).  In there, you'll see that there is a `ref()` method.  There is no `reference()`.  Maybe that's what you meant to use.

```
  const ref = admin.database().ref('messages/{pushId}');
```

Also, this is what you'll see in the example code in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#node.js).  Please review that to make sure you're following the correct examples for JavaScript.